# android displays no database

Tags: android, database, listview, listadapter

this is myclass eyehelper, which preloades a database from a text file

```
    public class EyeHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
      private static final String TAG = "EyeDatabase";
      //private static final String DB_DIR = "/data/data/test.eyedb/databases/";
      private static final String DB_NAME="eyeDB.sqlite";
      //private static String DB_PATH = DB_DIR + DB_NAME;
      private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;
      private final Context myContext = null;
      private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

  public EyeHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
  }



  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DiseaseTable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Disease TEXT NOT NULL, Definition TEXT NOT NULL, Remedy TEXT NOT NULL);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO DiseaseTable VALUES(1,'Nilsen', 'Johan', 'Bakken 2');");
    loadDB();
  }
  private void loadDB() {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              try {
                  loadWords();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  throw new RuntimeException(e);
              }
          }
      }).start();
  }

  private void loadWords() throws IOException {
      Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");
      final Resources resources = myContext.getResources();
      InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.dbtest);
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

      try {
          String line;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
              if (strings.length < 3) continue;
              long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim(), strings[2].trim());
              if (id < 0) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
              }
          }
      } finally {
          reader.close();
      }
      Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
  }

  /**
   * Add a word to the dictionary.
   * @return rowId or -1 if failed
   */
  public long addWord(String disease, String definition, String remedy) {
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      cv.put("disease", disease);
      cv.put("definition", definition);
      cv.put("remedy", remedy);
      return mDatabase.insert("DiseaseTable", null, cv);
  }


  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
              + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DiseaseTable");
      onCreate(db);
  }

  public Cursor getAll() {
    return(getReadableDatabase()
            .rawQuery("SELECT * FROM DiseaseTable",
                      null));
  }

  public void insert(String disease, String definition,
                     String remedy) {
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    cv.put("disease", disease);
    cv.put("definition", definition);
    cv.put("remedy", remedy);


    getWritableDatabase().insert("Disease", "disease", cv);
  }

  public String getDisease(Cursor c) {
    return(c.getString(1));
  }

  public String getDefinition(Cursor c) {
    return(c.getString(2));
  }

  public String getRemedy(Cursor c) {
    return(c.getString(3));
  }
}
```

and this is my main activity

```
public class EyeDBActivity extends TabActivity {
  Cursor model=null;
  EyeAdapter adapter=null;
  TextView disease;
  TextView definition;
  TextView remedy;
  EyeHelper helper=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    helper=new EyeHelper(this);

    disease=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.disease);
    definition=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.definition);
    remedy=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.remedy);

    //sButton save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

    //save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    model=helper.getAll();
    startManagingCursor(model);
    adapter=new EyeAdapter(model);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec=getTabHost().newTabSpec("tag1");

    spec.setContent(R.id.list);
    spec.setIndicator("Search", getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.list));
    getTabHost().addTab(spec);

    spec=getTabHost().newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.details);
    spec.setIndicator("Information", getResources()
                                  .getDrawable(R.drawable.restaurant));
    getTabHost().addTab(spec);

    getTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    helper.close();
  }

  /*private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      String type=null;

      switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.sit_down:
          type="sit_down";
          break;
        case R.id.take_out:
          type="take_out";
          break;
        case R.id.delivery:
          type="delivery";
          break;
      }

      helper.insert(name.getText().toString(),
                    address.getText().toString(), type,
                    notes.getText().toString());
      model.requery();
    }
  };*/

  private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                              View view, int position,
                              long id) {
      model.moveToPosition(position);
      disease.setText(helper.getDisease(model));
      definition.setText(helper.getDefinition(model));
      remedy.setText(helper.getRemedy(model));
      getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
    }
  };

  class EyeAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    EyeAdapter(Cursor c) {
      super(EyeDBActivity.this, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt,
                         Cursor c) {
      EyeHolder holder=(EyeHolder)row.getTag();

      holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c,
                         ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
      View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
      EyeHolder holder=new EyeHolder(row);

      row.setTag(holder);

      return(row);
    }
  }

  static class EyeHolder {
    private TextView disease;

    EyeHolder(View row) {
      disease=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, EyeHelper helper) {
      disease.setText(helper.getDisease(c));
    }
  }
}
```

i don't know why my program don't display my database on create,
even though i put the adapter onto the listview

Answer (score 0):

Your doing it a little different then I would so it's hard for me to say whats wrong. It looks like your calling your setText incorrectly. You shouldn't have to put your settext method in your holder. In your bind should be fine. I don't think you will need to call your cursor on it either since it should automatically do that based on what cursor was set in your adapter. If you haven't seen this link yet it should help. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_standard

It's helped me a lot with building custom adapters.